# How do I make a string system for my programming language?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a programming language in python and want to make a string system like in Java, JS, Python, C++ and (almost) every other programming language. Can somebody make the code?

I want a string to be converted to the arguments of the string reader.

Comment: Sorry for the bad english xD

Comment: If you don’t know how to write Python code, it’s too early to be using Python to implement your own language.